# How do I write this equation?

Tags: equations, symbols, greek, article, boldsymbol

I am trying to write some Greek text in PDF, but the first word of the equation is incomprehensible to me.

[image: fig]

Comment: They are `\mathcal{T}` and `\mathcal{S}`.

Comment: By the way, see also [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% <-- for aligned environment

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
        \mathcal{T}&=\{(x,\xi) \mid 0\leq\xi\leq x\leq 1\} \\
        \mathcal{T}_1&=\mathcal{T}\times\{t\geq 0\} \\
        \mathcal{S}&=\{(x,\xi) \mid 0\leq x\leq\xi\leq 1\} \\
        \mathcal{S}_1&=\mathcal{S}\times\{t\geq 0\}
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: Result]

### EDIT

Alternatively, `align*` environment will also do. (Thanks to [sigur](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14757/sigur))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% <-- for align environment

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \mathcal{T}&=\{(x,\xi) \mid 0\leq\xi\leq x\leq 1\} \\
        \mathcal{T}_1&=\mathcal{T}\times\{t\geq 0\} \\
        \mathcal{S}&=\{(x,\xi) \mid 0\leq x\leq\xi\leq 1\} \\
        \mathcal{S}_1&=\mathcal{S}\times\{t\geq 0\}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or, you can use `align*` directly.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you for pointing that out. I often write equations with their number tags so `aligned` just came out of my instinct.

Comment: `align` and `align*` open math mode and it is easy to alternate between them with you want to hide or show equation numbers.

Comment: @Sigur That's right. It is my writing habit that prefers only one equation tag for all.